# Nativescript location runtime updates

Tags: javascript, lua, location, nativescript

I'm new to Nativescript (used to be a Corona/Lua developer) and I need to create a function (similar to a RuntimeEventListener in Lua) that constantly gets user location and updates a dashboard with speed and altitude, for example.

My current code gets this info only when a button is pressed (which does not make sense for the kind of app I am trying to build). Question is, how to create and invoke such listener/function?

I am coding in Javascript and below it is my current code:

```
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;
var frames = require("ui/frame");

var orientation = require('nativescript-orientation');
  orientation.enableRotation(); // The screen will  rotate 
  console.log(orientation.getOrientation());  // Returns the enum DeviceOrientation value

var dialogs = require("ui/dialogs");  

// Get geo coordinates
var geolocation = require("nativescript-geolocation");
if (!geolocation.isEnabled()) {
        geolocation.enableLocationRequest();
}
/*
var watchID
watchId = geolocation.watchLocation(
    function (loc) {
        if (loc) {
            console.log("(watchid) Received location: " + loc);
        }
    }, 
    function(e){
        console.log("(watchid) Error: " + e.message);
    }, 
    {desiredAccuracy: 3, updateDistance: 10, minimumUpdateTime : 1000 * 20}); // should update every 20 sec according to google documentation this is not so sure.
*/


    //variables for the dashboard and the Origin 
    var originLoc //holds the lat,long of the starting point
    var originHeading = "NNW"
    var originTime = "0"
    var originDistance = "0"

    var mySpeed = "0"
    var myDuration = "00:00"
    var myDistance = "0"
    var myAltitude = "0";
    var myDirection;

    var butAction = "START" //button action when it starts

var fbMeasurement = "imperial";

//Sets the right heading of the compass (if landscape, subtracts 90 degrees)
function headingCompass(args) {
    var compassHead = "";

    if (args>12 && args<=34) {
        compassHead = "NNE";
    } else if (args>34 && args<=57) {
        compassHead = "NE";
    } else if (args>57 && args<=80) {
        compassHead = "ENE";
    } else if (args>80 && args<=102) {
        compassHead = "E";
    } else if (args>102 && args<=124) {
        compassHead = "ESE";
    } else if (args>124 && args<=147) {
        compassHead = "SE";
    } else if (args>147 && args<=170) {
        compassHead = "SSE";
    } else if (args>170 && args<=192) {
        compassHead = "S";
    } else if (args>192 && args<=215) {
        compassHead = "SSW";
    } else if (args>215 && args<=237) {
        compassHead = "SW";
    } else if (args>237 && args<=260) {
        compassHead = "WSW";
    } else if (args>260 && args<=282) {
        compassHead = "W";
    } else if (args>282 && args<=305) {
        compassHead = "WNW";
    } else if (args>305 && args<=327) {
        compassHead = "NW";
    } else if (args>327 && args<=350) {
        compassHead = "NNW";
    } else {
        compassHead = "N";
    }  
    return compassHead;
}



//Gets current location when app starts
var geolocation = require("nativescript-geolocation");
if (!geolocation.isEnabled()) {
        geolocation.enableLocationRequest();
}
var location = geolocation.getCurrentLocation({desiredAccuracy: 3, updateDistance: 10, maximumAge: 20000, timeout: 20000}).
then(function(loc) {
    if (loc) {
        console.log("Current location is: " + loc);
        originLoc = loc;
        if (fbMeasurement === "imperial") {
            myAltitude = parseInt(loc.altitude * 3.28084);
            mySpeed = (loc.speed * 2.23694).toFixed(1);
        } else {
            mySpeed = loc.speed.toFixed(1);
            myAltitude = parseInt(loc.altitude);
        }
        myDirection = headingCompass(loc.direction)
    }
}, function(e){
    console.log("Error: " + e.message);
});


function createViewModel() {
    var viewModel = new Observable();

    viewModel.originHeading = originHeading;
    viewModel.originTime = originTime;
    viewModel.originDistance = originDistance;

    viewModel.mySpeed = mySpeed;
    viewModel.myDuration = myDuration;
    viewModel.myDistance = myDistance;
    viewModel.myAltitude = myAltitude;

    viewModel.butAction = butAction;


    //STARTs
    var watchid;
    viewModel.onTapStart = function(args) {
        if (butAction==="START") {

            //change button color to RED
            var btn = args.object;
            btn.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
            //change button text to "STOP"
            this.set("butAction","STOP");
            butAction = "STOP";

            watchId = geolocation.watchLocation(
            function (loc) {
                if (loc) {
                    console.log("Received location: " + loc);

                    if (fbMeasurement === "imperial") {
                        myAltitude = parseInt(loc.altitude * 3.28084);
                        mySpeed = (loc.speed * 2.23694).toFixed(1);
                    } else {
                        mySpeed = loc.speed.toFixed(1);
                        myAltitude = parseInt(loc.altitude);
                    }
                    myDirection = headingCompass(loc.direction);


                }
            }, 
            function(e){
                console.log("Error: " + e.message);
            }, 
            {desiredAccuracy: 3, updateDistance: 10, minimumUpdateTime : 1000 * 1}); // should update every 20 sec according to google documentation this is not so sure.

        } else {
            //change button color to GREEN
            var btn = args.object;
            btn.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
            //change button text to "START"
            this.set("butAction","START")
            butAction = "START";

            if (watchId) {
                geolocation.clearWatch(watchId);
            }
        }


        this.set("myAltitude",myAltitude);
        this.set("mySpeed",mySpeed);
        this.set("myDistance",myDirection);



    }

    return viewModel;
}

exports.createViewModel = createViewModel;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **watchlocation** method is, in fact, a listener and will update your location when it is changed (based on this [arguments](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation-demo/blob/release/demo/app/views/main-page.ts#L76)). However, you will need to use some **observable** properties to update the info and reuse it where and when needed. Also, keep in mind that in Android the location is sometimes triggered after some distance (in my case approx. 100 steps gave the difference in the fourth sign after the dot).

If you are familiar with [MVVM pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) this is the one used on regular basis in NativeScript applications.[Here you can find the article for Data Binding in NativeScript](http://uatdocs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding#two-way-binding-in-code).

So basically just execute your watch function (e.g. using **loaded** event for your **Page**) and then watch for changes in the Observable model (e.g. create Observable property latitude and use the updated info when and where needed)

e.g.

```
vm = new Observable();
vm.set("altitude", someDefaultValue);
vm.set("longitude", someDefaultValue);

geolocation.watchLocation(function(loc) { 
   vm.set("altitude", loc.altitude);
   vm.set("longitude", loc.longitude);

   console.log(vm.get("altitude")); // Observable model updated
   console.log(vm.get("longitude"));
})
```